# How to create an array from output of var_dump in PHP?

Tags: php, var-dump

How can I parse the output of `var_dump` in PHP to create an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert var\_dump of array back to array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [var_export](http://php.net/var_export) if you want a representation which is also valid PHP code

```
$a = array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c"));
$dump=var_export($a, true);
echo $dump;
```

will display

```
array (
 0 => 1,
 1 => 2,
 2 => 
 array (
   0 => 'a',
   1 => 'b',
   2 => 'c',
 ),
)
```

To turn that back into an array, you can use eval, e.g.

```
eval("\$foo=$dump;");
var_dump($foo);
```

Not sure *why* you would want to do this though. If you want to store a PHP data structure somewhere and then recreate it later, check out [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) and [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize) which are more suited to this task.

Comment: This is WRONG. It doesn't produce an array, it just makes $foo a string, which is equal to $dump, which is also a string, which should be parsed.

Comment: No it does not work. When I take the outputtet string, comment out your first two lines and set $dump to this outputted string (wither html or text), I get an syntax error.
So it's different to use a var_export-ed variable and to only have a already var_dump-ed string.

Comment: If you get a syntax error you're doing something wrong. I'd suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and rather than having to tweak some code to turn my var_dump into the correct PHP multi-dimensional array syntax, I simply converted my array to YAML. This format is more readable and can fit in a single variable or in a hard .yml file.

Then you can convert it as you like to php array or JSON. For me it is the easiest solution to store dynamic tables while keeping readability.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you’re looking for [`var_export`](http://docs.php.net/var_export) that will give you a valid PHP expression of the passed value.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem : a long runing script produced at the end a vardump of large array. I had to parse it back somehow for further analyzis.
My solution was like this:

```
cat log.stats  | 
  sed 's/\[//g' | 
  sed 's/\]//g' | 
  sed -r 's/int\(([0-9]+)\)/\1,/g' | 
  sed 's/\}/\),/g' | 
  sed -r 's/array\([0-9]+\) \{/array(/g' > 
  log.stats.php
```

Comment: good answer, the only issue is if you have values contain strings ... so they get not wrapped by ''

Comment: Definitely it was just a quick hack which worked for my specific scenario. In general var_dump is horrible to parse back, so whenever possible I use something else (mostly json_encode). You are right that strings would cause problems. Huge problems if contain slashes or quotes. Moderate if contain something which itself looks like var dump output (=>, [8] or int(12)) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) just outputs text but doesn't return anything.

Comment: What about one having a string from var_dump via goold old copy paste? (I know people who copy paste huge var_dumps to text-files and send those text-files to me.)

Comment: @Seika85: You can tell them to use output buffering to get the result as a string. But for the purposes of this question this is still a »No« as they asked about getting an array.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are trying to convert an object to an array?
http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Object-To-Array-With-PHP.html

Answer (score 1):

[`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) creates the PHP code, which you can run through the [`eval`](http://php.net/eval).

But I wonder, what is your idea?