# json_encode an array of objects with private properties

Tags: php

I'm looking for an efficient way to use json_encode for an array of objects.  The issue I have is that my objects all have private properties (use getters and setters) and json_encode won't pull those in.  So I created a jsonSerialize function for an object with returns the private variables but I don't know how to execute the function for each object in the array efficiently.  I could use a loop to execute the jsonSerialize function for each object but that I'm afraid that may be too slow.

```
class car 
{
     private $make, $model;
     public function jsonSerialize()
     {
          return get_object_vars($this);
     }
}
```

Controller function to return list of cars in json format

```
$cars = $db->getAllCars();  //returns an array of objects using fetchall

return json_encode($cars);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005860/php-json-encode-class-private-members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `JsonSerializable` type like this:

```
class Car implements JsonSerializable
{
     private $make, $model;

     public function jsonSerialize() {
         return array($this->make, $this->model);
     }
} 

var $car = new Car();
echo json_encode($car, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't use json_encode for objects, it's written in the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

First you need to implement in your object the **JsonSerializable** interface to achieve what you're looking for (http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php).

In your case you're missing the interface declaration. Try this

```
class car  implements JsonSerializable
{
     private $make, $model;
     public function jsonSerialize()
     {
          return get_object_vars($this);
     }
}
```