# Iterate an array for HTML

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I have the following array but I am unsure how via a `foreach` I can break through the `key` so that I can use it in my HTML like this:  `<?php echo $key['cat_id'];?>`

**PHP:**

```
<?php foreach($by_category_manufacturer as $key ):?>
      <pre><?php var_dump($key)?></pre>
  <?php endforeach;?>
```

**Array:**

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#92 (5) {
    ["brand_name"]=>
    string(5) "Kioti"
    ["brand_id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["image_id"]=>
    string(2) "23"
    ["cat_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(9) "Machinery"
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `$key['cat_id'];` ? What's wrong with `$key->cat_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

convert your object to associative array, this may be done recursively

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating your array with json_decode, set the second parameter to `true`. I assume this is how that Object is being created?

```
$by_category_manufacturer = json_decode($json_string, true);

<?php foreach($by_category_manufacturer as $key => $object ):?>
    <pre><?php var_dump($object['cat_id'])?></pre>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

If not json, then cast it to an array: `$by_category_manufacturer = (array)$by_category_manufacturer;`