# How to traverse an object like it was an array (i.e. get key/val pairs) in Twig?

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

In Twig, how can I list all keys/value pairs from an object (read: private/protected properties), given that the proper getters exist?

```
class MyObject
{
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = 'bar';
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }

}
```

In the above example I'd like to get "foo" (the key) and "bar" (the value). Twig already let me do something like `myobject.foo` or `myobject['foo']` to get "bar".

The following doesn't work (array-like syntax):

```
{% for key, val in myobject %}
    {{ key }}={{ val }}
{% endfor %}
```

Should I implement [`Iterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface or there is a better/native way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Twig directly, but rather how PHP handles the iteration of objects.

So, for example, what happens if you do this?

```
class MyObject
{
  protected $foo;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->foo = 'bar';
  }

  public function getFoo()
  {
    return $this->foo;
  }
}

$myObject = new MyObject();

foreach ( $myObject as $property => $value )
{
  echo "$property: $value<br>";
}
```

Nothing. Zilch. Nada. A white screen in your browser.

However, if you cast your object as an array, then it works

```
foreach ( (array) $myObject as $property => $value )
{
  echo "$property: $value<br>";
}

// *foo: bar
```

*What's up with that asterisk? More on that later...*

However, you can't use PHP's explicit type casting in Twig. So what now? Enter [IteratorAggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php)

```
class MyObject implements \IteratorAggregate
{
  protected $foo;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->foo = 'bar';
  }

  public function getFoo()
  {
    return $this->foo;
  }

  public function getIterator()
  {
    return new \ArrayIterator( (array) $this );
  }
}
```

However, you will still have one issue: that darned asterisk. It's there because `MyObject::$foo` is `protected` - PHP automatically does this when the type is converted from **MyObject** to **array**.  So, what now?  Well, there are other ways to expose/create iterators on objects. You could always do it "manually"

```
  public function getIterator()
  {
    return new \ArrayIterator( array(
      'foo' => $this->getFoo()
    ) );
  }
```

You could alternatively implement [Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or go even deeper down the rabbit's hole and inherit from [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

Comment: I guess I can use `get_object_vars` from inside `MyObject` class for getting all protected/private properties and expose them, right? Are you sure that there isn't a Twig helper to to this?

Comment: No, because Twig isn't going to know which properties of your object are supposed to be "iterable".  Remember - Twig templates are compiled down to native PHP in the caching layer anyways, so when you write `{{ for p, v in obj }}`, at some point in the execution that becomes `foreach ($obj as $p => $v)`. A word of warning about using `get_object_vars()` - that reads from the properties directly and *will not* use getters, so if you rely on your getters for specific functionality, that will be lost by using `get_object_vars()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a solution other than Iterator (which personally I would go with), you could create a twig extension that provides a filter:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

From here you can manipulate the object however you wish.  For example a `to_array` filter, that accepts various types of values and converts them (to the best of its ability) to an array, eg:

[Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

```
{% for key, val in myobject|to_array %}
    {{ key }}={{ val }}
{% endfor %}
```

However this is simply providing you with the solution you asked for, Peter's method is generally better practice.