# using implode for stdClass Objects in php

Tags: php, implode

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    print_r($category);
}
```

The code above gives me the following result.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [category_Id] => 4
    [category_Title] => cat 4
)
stdClass Object
(
    [category_Id] => 7
    [category_Title] => cat 7
)
stdClass Object
(
    [category_Id] => 6
    [category_Title] => cat 6
)
```

how can I use `implode(', ' )` to get the following result:

> cat 4, cat 7, cat 6

I used it, but I got an error

Comment: just create array of element with category_Title

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can cast the object as an array.

```
implode(',',(array) $categories);
```

For more information:
[Convert a PHP object to an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Comment: it works for array but not for object as OP requested

Comment: You can indeed cast an object to array, but casting `$categories` and imploding the result does not make any sense. This answer is seemingly trying to concatenate the properties of a single object, as in `implode(',', (array)$category)`, but that would produce `'4,cat 4'`.

Answer (score 24):

Here's an alternative solution using [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$str = implode(', ', array_map(function($c) {
    return $c->category_Title;
}, $categories));
```

Comment: @Magus you misunderstood the question. If you read carefully,  `$categories` is *already* an array containing three `stdClass` elements which have two properties: `category_Id` and `category_Title`. He asked how to generate a new array of category titles (strings). Just casting `$categories` to an array wouldn't work.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn indeed. I apologize.

Answer (score 7):

Try like

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    $new_arr[] = $category->category_Title;
}
$res_arr = implode(',',$new_arr);
print_r($res_arr);
```

Comment: oky but to for loop array  will make your app slowly little bit, imagine it if you have more than 5000 records