# convert array of object to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to convert below array:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [risk_reference] => 
            [risk_version] => 
            [bsi] => 10.00
        )

)
```

to below array:-

```
Array
(
     [id] => 
     [risk_reference] => 
     [risk_version] => 
     [bsi] => 10.00

)
```

I tried to do it by **typecasting**. But It didn't give me the output. 
I also checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

For Above **$result = (array)($array[0])** works fine for me.

But if I have the below then what will I do?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [risk_reference] => 
            [risk_version] => 
            [bsi] => 10.00
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [risk_reference] => 
            [risk_version] => 
            [bsi] => 20.00
        )

)
```

Comment: `$result = (array)($array[0])`. You take the element with key `0` and cast it to array, there's nothing extraordinary going on.

Comment: Yes @Jon it really did my job. Thanks for this excellent solutions. But 1 question. If I have more than one object element then what will I do?

Comment: I can't answer that with confidence because you haven't said what result you will be expecting. Why not edit the question and give an example for that case too? This will allow people to help you better.

Comment: @Jon Your first answer is great for me. For my second question - I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$array = (array)($array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$yourArray = array();
$i=0;
foreach ($yourObject as $key => $value) {
    $yourArray[$i]['id'] = $value->id;
    $yourArray[$i]['risk_reference'] = $value->risk_reference;
    $yourArray[$i]['risk_version'] = $value->risk_version;
    $yourArray[$i]['bsi'] = $value->bsi;
    $i+=1;
}
print_r($yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/get_object_vars

Gets the accessible non-static properties of the given object according to scope.

Returns an associative array of defined object accessible non-static properties for the specified object in scope. If a property has not been assigned a value, it will be returned with a NULL value.