# Create array from objects php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a JSON result file that is decoded into an array of objects. I am using a Foreach to find the correct `player` and then wish to create an array with all the information under the correct player.

This is a snippet of the array of objects:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["result"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (18) {
    ["players"]=>
    array(10) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#5 (24) {
        ["account_id"]=>
        int(72775718)
        ["player_slot"]=>
        int(0)
        ["hero_id"]=>
        int(46)
        ["item_0"]=>
        int(50)
        ["item_1"]=>
        int(139)
        ["item_2"]=>
        int(149)
        ["item_3"]=>
        int(147)
        ["item_4"]=>
        int(168)
        ["item_5"]=>
        int(116)
        ["kills"]=>
        int(26)
        ["deaths"]=>
        int(10)
        ["assists"]=>
        int(9)
        ["leaver_status"]=>
        int(0)
        ["gold"]=>
        int(1622)
        ["last_hits"]=>
        int(285)
```

There are several `players` in this, and I am using the `account_id` to find the correct player with:

```
foreach ($data_decoded->result->players as $val){
            if($val->account_id == $this->PlayerID){
                echo "found you!"."\n";
}
```

How do I then create an array with all of the subsequent results? For example, underneath the `account_id`, I would like to store all of that information (`player_slot`, `hero_id`, etc.) Do I need to use another foreach?  If so I honestly don't know how to word it.

I have tried:

```
    foreach ($data_decoded->result->players as $val){
        if($val->account_id == $this->PlayerID){
            echo "found you!"."\n"; 
            foreach($val as $test){
                $dataarray=array($test);

            }
```

but this only adds the values that are on the same "level" (poor terminology) as $val, and not the subsequent values?

Comment: `if($val->account_id == $this->PlayerID) $dataarray = (array) $val`?

Comment: `$val` is an individual player object. You should be able to get `player_slot`, `hero_id`, etc as properties of `$val`.

Comment: @Peehaa oh wow. That was easy. Didn't know I could do that! Do you want to write that as an answer, and I can give you the credit for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to change it into an array you can [simply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array) cast [it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

```
if ($val->account_id == $this->PlayerID) {
    $dataarray = (array) $val;
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/116967