# php - accessing class object properties like associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

so i'm having a php class like the following:

```
class myClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->chart_data = array(1,2,3,4,5);
        $this->captions   = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    }
}
```

is there a way to access the properties the same way like an associative array, like:

```
$obj = new myClass();
echo $obj['chart_data'];
echo $obj['captions'];
```

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Comment: There is an interface for that: http://php.net/ArrayAccess
Implement its methods, and you're ready to go...

Comment: that's what i've been looking for - thanks fracsi

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
echo $obj->{'chart_data'};
echo $obj->{'captions'};
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array) you can try like this

```
$obj = (array) new myClass();
print_r($obj);
```