# Merge one array with object of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one object having an array like

```
object(ElggObject)[1023]
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array
      'guid' => string '39344' (length=5)
      'type' => string 'object' (length=6)
      'subtype' => string '25' (length=2)
      'owner_guid' => string '39136' (length=5)
      'container_guid' => string '39136' (length=5)
      'site_guid' => string '1' (length=1)
      'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'time_created' => string '1359536708' (length=10)
      'time_updated' => string '1359536708' (length=10)
      'last_action' => string '1359536708' (length=10)
      'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)
      'tables_split' => int 2
      'tables_loaded' => int 2
      'title' => string 'Community developer 5' (length=21)
      'description' => string '<p>$entity = get_entity($entity_guid);</p>' (length=42)
  protected 'url_override' => null
  protected 'icon_override' => null
  protected 'temp_metadata' => 
    array
      empty.........
```

The above one only one object. And another array having an array of obejcts like below.
So i need to merge two things..

```
array
  0 => 
    object(ElggObject)[1031]
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array
          'guid' => string '35116' (length=5)
          'type' => string 'object' (length=6)
          'subtype' => string '25' (length=2)
          'owner_guid' => string '2' (length=1)
          'container_guid' => string '2' (length=1)
          'site_guid' => string '1' (length=1)
          'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time_created' => string '1322222868' (length=10)
          'time_updated' => string '1402048391' (length=10)
          'last_action' => string '1322222868' (length=10)
          'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)
          'tables_split' => int 2
          'tables_loaded' => int 2
          'title' => string 'Developer for Ramco Systems' (length=27)
          'description' => string '<ul>

  1 => 
    object(ElggObject)[1034]
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array
          'guid' => string '39339' (length=5)
          'type' => string 'object' (length=6)
          'subtype' => string '25' (length=2)
          'owner_guid' => string '39136' (length=5)
          'container_guid' => string '39136' (length=5)
          'site_guid' => string '1' (length=1)
          'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time_created' => string '1359535318' (length=10)
          'time_updated' => string '1402032776' (length=10)
          'last_action' => string '1359535318' (length=10)
          'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)
          'tables_split' => int 2
          'tables_loaded' => int 2
          'title' => string 'Community developer 2' (length=21)
          'description' => string '<p>Job description jkjkhjkhk</p>' (length=32)

  2 => 
    object(ElggObject)[1037]
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array
          'guid' => string '39342' (length=5)
          'type' => string 'object' (length=6)
          'subtype' => string '25' (length=2)
          'owner_guid' => string '39136' (length=5)
          'container_guid' => string '39136' (length=5)
          'site_guid' => string '1' (length=1)
          'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time_created' => string '1359536322' (length=10)
          'time_updated' => string '1401962732' (length=10)
          'last_action' => string '1359536322' (length=10)
          'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)
          'tables_split' => int 2
          'tables_loaded' => int 2
          'title' => string 'Community developer 4' (length=21)
```

So how to merge two things...i tried `array_merge` but didn't worked for me ...

Any suggestion..

Comment: convert an object to an array and then merge http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array

Comment: @Jack The expected outcome will be the first object should be added as first index for second array.

Comment: @Jack i didn't got your point

Comment: okay the object(ElggObject)[1023] will add before object(ElggObject)[1031]

Comment: I've given up on this question, it's completely unclear what you want to do, especially without any code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
$result = (object)array_merge((array)$obj1, (array)$obj2);
```

Comment: But i need end result as array only its converting to an object what to do ?

Comment: OK then you can do in this way. 

$result = array_merge((array)$obj1, (array)$obj2);

Comment: can you tell me what is the $obj1 & $obj2 ?

Comment: Well, these are the object of arrays. 

Such as in your case 

$obj1 = object(ElggObject)[1023];
$obj2 = object(ElggObject)[1031];

Comment: its adding to the array but its not starting with 0 index...

Comment: well, array_merge will only merge with same type of elements. As far as indexes, you need to manually then.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

```
$secondArray[] = $firstArrayObj;
```

Try this one. I hope this works.

Comment: You can try the one Naveed Ramzan mentioned.

Comment: What you meant to write is identical to: `$secondArray[] = $firstArrayObj`.

Comment: But its returning the count i need the array ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge_recursive function in PHP to merge multidimensional array.

For example,

```
$ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
$ar2 = array("color1" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
print_r($result);
```

The important thing is Key should be different. If key is unique the values will be merged from different array having same key.