# get data from google's unofficial dictionary API

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the synonyms of a word from Google's unofficial dictionary API, but I can't figure out how to select the data I want. This is the URL I'm using:

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/scribe/v1/research?key=AIzaSyDqVYORLCUXxSv7zneerIgC2UYMnxvPeqQ&dataset=dictionary&dictionaryLanguage=en&query=hello'
```

Then I do this:

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;
```

Everything is returned correctly, but as a string, so I can't figure out how to isolate the synonyms. I've tried `simplexml_load_file($url);` but I can't get anything to echo/print from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code you want:

```
 <?php
function object_to_array($data)
{
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[$key] = object_to_array($value);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $data;
}

function getSynonims($word)
{
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/scribe/v1/research?key=AIzaSyDqVYORLCUXxSv7zneerIgC2UYMnxvPeqQ&dataset=dictionary&dictionaryLanguage=en&query='.$word;
    $ret = null;
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = object_to_array(json_decode($data));
    if (isset($data['data'][0]['dictionary']['definitionData']['0']['meanings'][0]['synonyms']))
        $synonyms = $data['data'][0]['dictionary']['definitionData']['0']['meanings'][0]['synonyms'];
    foreach ($synonyms as $key => $synonym) {
        $ret[$key] = $synonym['nym'];
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

**example**:

```
$word = 'house';
print_r(getSynonims($word));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => residence
    [1] => home
    [2] => place of residence
)
```

**useful**:

- **[object_to_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)**
- **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**

Answer (score 1):

It's JSON, so parse it like:

```
$data = json_decode($url);
```

[See PHP docs on json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Additionally, you can use this super helpful tool [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to check if that string will parse to proper JSON.