# Convert laravel object to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

Laravel output:

```
Array
(
    [0] = stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] = 5

    )

    [1] = stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] = 4

    )

)
```

I want to convert this into normal array. Just want to remove that `stdClass Object`. I also tried using `->toArray();` but I get an error:

> Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object.

How can I fix this?

Functionalities have been Implemented on http://www.srihost.com

Comment: did this object came from the DB? i haven't used laravel, but maybe the have an API that results an associative array instead of objects. no need to convert the whole object and then transfer them into another array

Comment: yes it came from DB..

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658891/converting-object-to-array-in-laravel/35414167#35414167

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**UPDATE since version 5.4 of Laravel it is no longer possible.**

You can change your db config, like @Varun suggested, or if you want to do it just in this very case, then:

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// then
DB::table(..)->get(); // array of arrays instead of objects

// of course to revert the fetch mode you need to set it again
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

For New Laravel above 5.4 (Ver > 5.4) 
see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade fetch mode section

```php
Event::listen(StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
    $event->statement->setFetchMode(...);
});
```

Comment: I think you should add to your question this will change fetch mode for all queries not only for this one. But nice to know it can be also changed this way

Comment: Yes, it will affect all the queries for this request unless you revert it. Edited to make it clear.

Comment: you can also edit config/database.php, replace 'fecth' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: This no longer work on new laravel since version 5.4 They scrap this away

Answer (score 45):

```
foreach($yourArrayName as $object)
{
    $arrays[] = $object->toArray();
}
// Dump array with object-arrays
dd($arrays);
```

Or when `toArray()` fails because it's a stdClass

```
foreach($yourArrayName as $object)
{
    $arrays[] =  (array) $object;
}
// Dump array with object-arrays
dd($arrays);
```

Not working? Maybe you can find your answer here:

[Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Answer (score 19):

Just in case somebody still lands here looking for an answer. It can be done using plain PHP. 
An easier way is to reverse-json the object.

```
function objectToArray(&$object)
{
    return @json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

this worked for me:

```
$data=DB::table('table_name')->select(.......)->get();
$data=array_map(function($item){
    return (array) $item;
},$data);
```

or

```
$data=array_map(function($item){
    return (array) $item;
},DB::table('table_name')->select(.......)->get());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also get all the result always as array by changing

```
// application/config/database.php

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
 // to
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me in laravel 5.4

```
$partnerProfileIds = DB::table('partner_profile_extras')->get()->pluck('partner_profile_id');
$partnerProfileIdsArray = $partnerProfileIds->all();
```

output

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "8219c678-2d3e-11e8-a4a3-648099380678"
  1 => "28459dcb-2d3f-11e8-a4a3-648099380678"
  2 => "d5190f8e-2c31-11e8-8802-648099380678"
  3 => "6d2845b6-2d3e-11e8-a4a3-648099380678"
]
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-all

Answer (score 6):

Use the `toArray()` method to convert an object to array:

```
$foo = Bar::first(); // Get object
$foo = $foo->toArray(); // Convert object to array
```

Answer (score 5):

It's also possible to typecast an object to an array. That worked for me here.

`(array) $object;`

will convert

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 4
)
```

to

```
Array(
    [id] => 4
)
```

Had the same problem when trying to pass data from query builder to a view. Since data comes as object. So you can do:

```
$view = view('template', (array) $object);
```

And in your view you use variables like

```
{{ $id }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the array

```
for ($i = 0, $c = count($array); $i < $c; ++$i) {
    $array[$i] = (array) $array[$i];
}
```

ans use `(array)` conversion because you have array of objects of Std class and not object itself

**Example:**

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

var_dump($users);

echo "<br /><br />";

for ($i = 0, $c = count($users); $i < $c; ++$i) {
    $users[$i] = (array) $users[$i];
}
var_dump($users);
exit;
```

Output for this is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#258 (8) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["user_name"]=> string(5) "admin" ["email"]=> string(11) "admin@admin" ["passwd"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$T/0fW18gPGgz0CILTy2hguxNpcNjYZHsTyf5dvpor9lYMw/mtKYfi" ["balance"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["remember_token"]=> string(60) "moouXQOJFhtxkdl9ClEXYh9ioBSsRp28WZZbLPkJskcCr0325TyrxDK4al5H" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-10-01 12:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2014-09-27 12:20:54" } }

array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["user_name"]=> string(5) "admin" ["email"]=> string(11) "admin@admin" ["passwd"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$T/0fW18gPGgz0CILTy2hguxNpcNjYZHsTyf5dvpor9lYMw/mtKYfi" ["balance"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["remember_token"]=> string(60) "moouXQOJFhtxkdl9ClEXYh9ioBSsRp28WZZbLPkJskcCr0325TyrxDK4al5H" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-10-01 12:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2014-09-27 12:20:54" } }
```

as expected. Object of `stdClass` has been converted to array.

Comment: i tried both methods.. same error `Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object
`

Comment: @user3436481 Have you tried using only `(array)` as I showed in my answer? You should edit your question and show how exactly you get data and how you use array conversion

Comment: Iam getting data from laravel database ... it uses `std class`  ...data is exactly same....

Comment: If you're using Laravel properly, it uses model objects and collections, not StdClass objects

Comment: @MarkBaker No, only Eloquent does it. If you use simple `Query\Builder` it returns exactly this `array` of `stdObjects` (by default, depending on the db config)

Answer (score 2):

Object to array

```
$array = (array) $players_Obj;  

$object = new StdClass;
$object->foo = 1;
$object->bar = 2;

var_dump( (array) $object );
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
    'foo' => int(1)
    'bar' => int(2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only ID in array, can use array_map:

```
    $data = array_map(function($object){
        return $object->ID;
    }, $data);
```

With that, return an array with ID in every pos.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. You can use like this :-

```
Suppose You have one users table and you want to fetch the id only
$users = DB::table('users')->select('id')->get();
$users = json_decode(json_encode($users)); //it will return you stdclass object
$users = json_decode(json_encode($users),true); //it will return you data in array
echo '<pre>'; print_r($users);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = ActivityServer::query()->select('channel_id')->where(['id' => $id])->first()->attributesToArray();
```

I use `get()`, it returns an object, I use the `attributesToArray()` to change the object attribute to an array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simply do this within your method

```
public function MyAwesomeMethod($returnQueryAs = null)
{
    $tablename = 'YourAwesomeTable';

    if($returnQueryAs == 'array')
    {
        DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    return DB::table($tablename)->get();
}
```

With this all you need is to pass the string 'array' as your argument and Voila! An Associative array is returned.

Comment: There is an unnecessary quote mark in the end of first line and that breaks the formatting.