# Converting object to array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel, type-conversion

i queried a DB like this which got me an array:

```
foreach($oid as $orderid) {
    $orderdetailData[] = DB::table('order_details')
        ->join('orders', 'order_details.oid', '=', 'orders.oid')
        ->select('order_details.oid', 'orders.ostatus')
        ->where('order_details.oid', $orderid)->get();
    }

    $data = array_flatten($orderdetailData);
    return $data;
```

This is the array i get

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[174]
      public 'oid' => int 1
      public 'ostatus' => string 'Placed' (length=6)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[158]
      public 'oid' => int 2
      public 'ostatus' => string 'Placed' (length=6)
```

I am trying to get this array in the form

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      public 'oid' => int 1
      public 'ostatus' => string 'Placed' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      public 'oid' => int 2
      public 'ostatus' => string 'Placed' (length=6)
```

I tried doing this:

```
foreach($orderdetailData as $key => $value){
    $data[] = array_flatten($orderdetailData[$key]);
}
```

But doing this gets me an array in this form:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[174]
          public 'oid' => int 1
          public 'ostatus' => string 'Placed' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[158]
          public 'oid' => int 2
          public 'ostatus' => string 'Placed' (length=6)
```

Which is not i what i am looking for. Can someone tell me what would be an easy way to do this ? Thanks

Comment: You can check the solution to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2476876/2688283). It explains how to convert an object to an array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `array_map` and casting to an array should be sufficient:

```
$data = array_map(function($object){
    return (array) $object;
}, $data);
```

I also wouldn't run queries inside a loop. You should try getting that data in one query from the db. Something like this could work:

```
$data = DB::table('order_details')
    ->join('orders', 'order_details.oid', '=', 'orders.oid')
    ->select('order_details.oid', 'orders.ostatus')
    ->whereIn('order_details.oid', $oid)->get();
```

### Edit

As it has been mentioned in another answer shortly let me explain how you can accomplish the same by setting PDO to `FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = DB::table('order_details') .... ->get();
```

However this changes the fetch mode globally for the rest of the request (at least if you don't open a new connection). To be save you should change it back afterwards:

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = DB::table('order_details') .... ->get();
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

Or even back it up first if you can't be sure what default is used:

```
$fetchModeBefore = DB::getFetchMode();
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = DB::table('order_details') .... ->get();
DB::setFetchMode($fetchModeBefore);
```

Comment: array_map() worked. Thanks for replying, learnt something new today :)

Comment: Beware of the performance draw backs from this.

Comment: I tried to get values directly from object but i am getting 'Cannot use object of type MyClass as array' error how can i get value directly from class

Answer (score 1):

On the PDO/DB object you can set the return style to assoc.