# PHP access object member as if array member

Tags: php, arrays, object

Is it possible to access to object member as if array member?

for example

```
echo $a->b;
```

to

```
echo $a[b];
```

Would it be any php ini settings, or this is quite impossible in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP object to associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried for a one-liner but:

```
$x = (array)$a;
echo $x['b'];
```

Or of course to convert the object: `$a = (array)$a;`

Answer (score 2):

`extends ArrayObject` or `implements ArrayAccess` so you can access the object as array.

**Reading Material**

[`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

[`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)