# How to Convert my Object to Array Php

Tags: php

I have an object in php.

```
Object ( [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array ( [Reservations] => Array ( ) [@metadata] => Array ( [statusCode] => 200 [effectiveUri] => https://google.com [headers] => Array ( [content-type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8 [transfer-encoding] => chunked [vary] => Accept-Encoding [date] => Fri, 27 Nov 2015 07:03:59 GMT [server] => AmazonEC2 ) ) ) )
```

I need to convert this object to array in php.

can i get any help please?

thanks.

Comment: Try `get_object_vars()` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP object to associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Answer (score 1):

Cast to an array

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

Or, use [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
$array = get_object_vars($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just typecast it:

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```

This will create an associative array from your object.

Answer (score 0):

Aws\Result has a method toArray()

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.ResultInterface.html#_toArray)