# Convert stdClass object to associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I need to convert this array

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object 
     ( [title] => primo ) 
[1] => stdClass Object 
     ( [title] => secondo ))
```

to

```
Array ( 
[primo] => primo
[secondo] => secondo )
```

Tried different options, including typecast,  still not found the correct solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP object to associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Comment: If I use json function I obtain this array
          Array ( 
                      [0] => Array ( [title] => primo ) 
                      [1] => Array ( [title] => secondo ) )

Comment: it's an array of objects merged into an associative array, not just an object to an array, might not be a duplicate

Answer (score 22):

Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($yourObject), TRUE);
```

json_decode() 's second parameter is set to `TRUE`.

Function definition:

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth  > = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )

That will convert your object into an associative array.

Comment: Simple solutions are why I love you Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I did it this:

```
$options = array('' => '<select>');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $id => $node) {
  $value = $node->title;
  $options[$value] = $value;
}
```

Thanks for all your answer

Answer (score 1):

Check this code please, I haven't debugged it...

```
$array = array_values($array);
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $row){
   $new_array[$row['title']] = $row['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$final_array = array();

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $final_array = array_merge($final_array, json_decode(json_encode($item), true);
}
```

Where `$items` is the name of your array.
Should go through your array of objects, convert that object to an associative array, and merge it into the `$final_array`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `array_walk` like as

```
$result = array();
array_walk($arr,function($v)use(&$result){ 
      $result[$v->title] = $v->title;
});
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

To blindly answer the title of the thread, you can achieve object conversion to an associative array by simply casting it:

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

However, in the discussed example, rudimentary operations can help generate the desired data structure without using any built-in function:

```
$array = [];
foreach ($arrayOfObjects as $object) {
    $title = $object->title ?? null;
    if (!is_null($title)) {
        $array[$title] = $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I don't think an array of objects will get casted to an array where the keys are set to some arbitrary element of the object

Comment: I was not trying to answer the specific case evoked by the question author as there is no built in function for that. There are infinite data structures and we can't create predefined methods to satisfy all. I just wanted to share a hint that can be used by the community if someone looks up the title of the thread.