# convert stdclassobject into array

Tags: php, arrays

i am laraval5.1. i am taking database table into array.

data is getting stored into stdclassobject.

i want to convert into normal array. how to do that

```
    $silver_plans = array();
    $silver_plans =  DB::select('select * from ins_gold ');
    print_r($silver_plans);
```

Dont know how to convert stdclass object into normal array

after storing database table ... by default it is storing data into into stdclass object. but i want to store into array

Comment: `print_r((array) $silver_plans)`

Comment: thanks...............

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP object to associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (built in in laravel 5):

```
$silver_plans =  DB::select('select * from ins_gold ')->toArray();
print_r($silver_plans);
```

Answer (score 0):

$array =  (array) $yourObject;

check [Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)