# How to work with not standart named array in object

Tags: php, object

I don't know how to work with such object, i need to get first and second one status value, tryed to convert it to json, but it gives me nothing. I just don't get it how to open array with such "_data:MailWizzApi_Params:private" name.

**Source:**

```
// SEARCH BY EMAIL
$response = $endpoint->emailSearch($myConfig["LIST-UNIQUE-ID"], $_GET["email"]);

// DISPLAY RESPONSE
echo '<hr /><pre>';
print_r($response->body);
echo '</pre>';
```

**I receive such answer**

```
MailWizzApi_Params Object
(
    [_data:MailWizzApi_Params:private] => Array
        (
            [status] => success
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [subscriber_uid] => an837jdexga45
                    [status] => unsubscribed
                )

        )

    [_readOnly:MailWizzApi_Params:private] => 
)
```

Comment: Try this = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array

Comment: `_data` is private)

Comment: It has `ArrayAccess` implemented. So, `$response->body['data']` will works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can't.
Because it's `private` field.

For public fields with "incorrect" names you can use snippet:

```
$name = '}|{';
$obj->$name;
```

So, let see to your property: `[_data:MailWizzApi_Params:private]`.

It is `private` field of instance of `MailWizzApi_Params` class with `_data` name.

Let's google to it's implementation: [Found](https://github.com/twisted1919/mailwizz-php-sdk/blob/master/MailWizzApi/Params.php)

As you can see it has `toArray` public method. Just use it.

```
print_r($response->body->toArray());
```

It has `ArrayAccess` implemented also. So, `$response->body['status']` or `$response->body['data']` will works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for fast answers, here is my dumb way if reading status value
(thanks, @Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez)

```
$toJson = json_encode((array)$response->body);
$toJson = str_replace(array("\u0000MailWizzApi_Params\u0000_"), "", $toJson);
```

So we receive a normal json:

```
{"data":{"status":"success","data":{"subscriber_uid":"an837jdexga45","status":"unsubscribed"}},"readOnly":false}
```

And now we need just to decode it

```
$json = json_decode($toJson, true);
echo $json['data']['status'];
```