# Codeigniter data using into controller

Tags: codeigniter

In my controller i'm using data variable like this

```
$data['some_var'] = $this->Model->some_info($param);
```

So if i do `var_dump` this `$data['some_var']` it will print like this

```
  object(StdClass)[4]
  Public 'blah1' => String 'blah1' (Length=5)
  Public 'blah2' => String 'blah2' (Length=5)
  Public 'blah3' => String 'blah3' (Length=5)
  Public 'blah4' => String 'blah4' (Length=5)
```

I know how to use this `$data[]` into view file but i want to use this `$data[]` into controller file,

What i want , i want to use `blah1` from array

I tried like this

```
$var = $data['some_var']['blah1'];

$var = $some_var->blah1;
```

I'm not sure how to sort-out this things

Comment: can you show `var_export()` result instead `var_dump()` so that we can try

Comment: array (
      0 => 
       stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'blah1' => 'blah1',
         'blah2' => 'blah2',
       )),
     )
Nothing Different , there has to be way but i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try this it will work

```
$var = $data['some_var'][0]->blah1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$var = $data['some_var']->blah1;
```

Comment: This won't working , this has to be way but i don't know how @Rana Soyab

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try the solution of typecasting your object - answer from Gordon : [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

```
// typecast your object
$data['some_var'] = (array) $this->Model->some_info($param);

// access the index of the array
// !! this won't work if ['blah1'] contains an Object !!
$var = $data['some_var']['blah1'];
```

If you want to access sub-object as well I guess you'll have to write a recursive function that will typecast every level [see Gordon's answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)