# Use list() with an object in PHP

Tags: php, list, casting

I would like to use the list() statement in combination with an object.

```
$tuple = new Tuple();
// ..
list ($guestbook, $entry, $author) = $tuple;
```

This would work if `$tuple` was an array with three elements. But its an object.

Is there any way without using a method of `Tuple` (returning that kind of array) like implementing a fancy native interface I yet don't know?

Comment: maybe if the object implemented an Iterator, but never tried list() with that, so no idea.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I will accept answers when I feel they are right. The given solutions are not very elegant, they "just" solve the technical problem which wasn't my question (I know how to convert an object into an array) - I am more curious about ideas behind this (casting objects, less dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the interface `ArrayAccess` to do so:

```
class Tuple implements ArrayAccess {
  private $arr;

  public function __construct($arr) {
    $this->arr = $arr;
  }

  public function offsetExists($offset) {
    return array_key_exists($offset, $this->arr);
  }

  public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return $this->arr[$offset];
  }

  public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
    return $this->arr[$offset] = $value;
  }

  public function offsetUnset($offset) {
    unset($this->arr[$offset]);
  }
}

$tuple = new Tuple([1, 2, 3]);

list($am, $stram, $gram) = $tuple;

echo $am;
echo $stram;
echo $gram;

// outputs: 123
```

Comment: Im a lazy programmer, so implementing four methods is not what I want - even though its a solution based on what I asked (but not really meant)

Answer (score 1):

See this previous post: 
[Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

I am assuming (I haven't tested it) you could then do:

`$tuple = new Tuple();
list ($guestbook, $entry, $author) = (array) $tuple;`

Comment: if this works, then it depends on the property order which I can't guarantee

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
$tumple = new Tumple();
$properties = get_object_vars($tumple);// ["guestbook" => "Feel", "entry" => "Good", "author" => "Inc"];
```