# how to convert stdclass object to array in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

first, i get the table value with jquery plugin name is tableToJson.
and the type is json object. then i converting the json object with JSON.stringify. and the result show like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Kode] => 450
        [Nama Menu] => ES JAHE/null
        [Sat] => TKO
        [Qty] => 1
        [Harga] => 25000
        [Jml Harga] => 25000
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Kode] => 310
        [Nama Menu] => NASI/null
        [Sat] => CTG
        [Qty] => 2
        [Harga] => 20000
        [Jml Harga] => 40000
    )

)
```

but i want the result is :

```
Array
(
[0](
        [Kode] => 450
        [Menu] => ES JAHE/null
        [Sat] => TKO
        [Qty] => 1
        [Harga] => 25000
        [price] => 25000
    )

[1](
        [Kode] => 310
        [Menu] => NASI/null
        [Sat] => CTG
        [Qty] => 2
        [Harga] => 20000
        [price] => 40000
    )

  )
```

how i'm get the result like that with data type is array without stdclass object.

Comment: try this code json_decode(json_encode($array), true);

Comment: What is that second code block supposed to be? Those are the same objects. as you're showing in the first block. You just removed the object's type from the output...

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554 and a couple others. Please use the search function before asking questions. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good question, which is not answered by the the duplicate, or Gordon's one. I still don't have an answer to it!

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the object to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties:

```
$resultArray =  (array) $obj;
```

you can perform this in a loop to get a multi-dimensional array of the StdClass objects you have in an array.

Comment: thats only work on php. not in javascript

Comment: there is nothing called StdClass in javascript.. you need to json encode the final array from php and read it in javascript