# Object to array convert

Tags: php, arrays, object, caldav

I use [the simpleCalDAV PHP library](https://github.com/wvrzel/simpleCalDAV) to work with a CalDAV calendar. So from the server I got information and put it into an array:

```
$rr = $client->getEvents("20160614T000000Z", "20180615T000000Z");
var_dump($rr);

array(77) {
  [0]=>
  object(CalDAVObject)#5 (3) {
    ["href":"CalDAVObject":private]=> string(91) "..."
    ["data":"CalDAVObject":private]=> string(3405) "..."
    ["etag":"CalDAVObject":private]=> string(13) "..."
  }
  [1]=>
  object(CalDAVObject)#6 (3) {
    ["href":"CalDAVObject":private]=> string(91) "..."
    ["data":"CalDAVObject":private]=> string(3405) "..."
    ["etag":"CalDAVObject":private]=> string(13) "..."
  }
  [1]=> ...
```

I try to convert it to array, but it fails too:

```
$array = (array) $rr[0];
var_dump($array);
```

[image]

What can i do?

Comment: `$array = (array) (json_decode($rr[0],true));var_dump($array);`  try this

Comment: there might be a getter and setter method to fetch and set elements. $events = $client->getCustomReport($filter->toXML());$events[0]->getHref(). like this

Comment: You say it fails yet the image suggests that it's not failing

Comment: check this https://github.com/wvrzel/simpleCalDAV/blob/master/example%20code/example.php and find echo $events[0]->getData();

Comment: can you try get_object_vars() ?

Comment: read this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array

Comment: @user7234862 it works! thanks! Maybe you know how can I next parse data from $events[0]->getData();? And can you answer this quasten - I accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [example.php](https://github.com/wvrzel/simpleCalDAV/blob/master/example%20code/example.php) file. Once you get the response write

```
  $events = $client->getEvents("20160614T000000Z", "20180615T000000Z");
  echo $events[0]->getData(); `
```

Everything is in example.php file with examples. Post your output with this if you still have doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Try with foreach:

```
foreach($rr as $key => $value ){
    $value["href"]
    $value["data"]
    $value["etag"]
}
```