# php - fputcsv Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, laravel

I use post method to download csv using php with `fputcsv` when i using get method it works, but when using post it give me error, cannot use stdClass as array, people mention to use `json_decode` but i'm not sure wher to place it,

I use laravel

CODE :

```
public function csv (Request $request) {

    $storage_path = storage_path();

    $from = date($request->from_date);
    $to = date($request->to_date);

    $table = DB::table('registrations')->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();



    $filename = "data.csv";
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

    fputcsv($handle, array('No', 'Nama', 'Nomor Telepon', 'Email', 'Tempat Tinggal',
        'Bank', 'Kartu Kredit', 'Rumah', 'Mobil', 'Luar Negeri', 'Penghasilan'));

    foreach($table as $row) {
            fputcsv($handle, array( $row['id'], $row['name'], $row['phonenumber'], $row['email'],
                            $row['umur'], $row['tempattinggal'],
                            $row['bank'], $row['kartukredit'], $row['rumah'],
                            $row['keluarnegeri'], $row['penghasilan'] ));
    }

    fclose($handle);

    $headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    );

    return Response::download($filename, 'data.csv', $headers);
}
```

the error happen to be on foreach,when i remove the for each , i can donwload the csv, but in badly format

Comment: `DB::table()` appears to be returning an object rather than an associative array - if you want an array, if it is possible to configure the database connection to fetch arrays, do so, otherwise, you should be able to just cast it to an array `$table = (array)$table;` or rather in the loop: `$row = (array)$row;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue with your code is that when fetching the records from the database they are being returned as object and you are trying to use that object as if it was an array.

You have 2 solutions, solution 1 is the most efficient:

**Solution 1:**
Use the variable `$row` as an object instead of an array

```
foreach($table as $row) {
    fputcsv($handle, array( $row->id, $row->name, $row->phonenumber, $row->email,$row->umur, $row->tempattinggal,$row->bank, $row->kartukredit, $row->rumah,$row->keluarnegeri, $row->penghasilan ));
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Convert the `$row` to an array for every loop

```
foreach($table as $row) {
    $row = json_decode(json_encode($row), True);
    //Or $row = (array)$row;
    fputcsv($handle, array( $row['id'], $row['name'], $row['phonenumber'], $row['email'],$row['umur'], $row['tempattinggal'],$row['bank'], $row['kartukredit'], $row['rumah'],$row['keluarnegeri'], $row['penghasilan'] ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need to do:

```
fputcsv($handle, json_encode(array($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['phonenumber'], $row['email'],
                        $row['umur'], $row['tempattinggal'],
                        $row['bank'], $row['kartukredit'], $row['rumah'],
                        $row['keluarnegeri'], $row['penghasilan'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

The query builder `get()` method returns a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) containing stdClass objects. You can convert that to an array with [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray) (it will also convert the inner objects to arrays).

```
$table = $table->toArray();
```

If you like, you can also add a [`select('id', 'name', ...etc.)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects) to your query builder to specify the columns you want. If you do that, then you can write to the file with

```
fputcsv($handle, $row);
```

rather than building a new array there.

Also, I'm not sure about the way you're creating the download response. You're writing to [php://output](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.output), which doesn't write to a file, but `Response::download()` expects a path to a file. I think you either need to write the results to a temp file instead, or use `streamDownload()` if you don't want to create a file locally.