# How to store data in Object to an array in php

Tags: php, xml

againAnotherChild is an object now how can i put the data from it to an array.

```
foreach($anotherChild->children() as $againAnotherChild) //child to 
//childchildchild
    {
        // echo "Inside Again child Tag attributes<br>";
        $againAnotherChildArray[] = $againAnotherChild->getName();
        //print_r($againAnotherChild);
//            foreach($this->$againAnotherChild[0] as $Storage)
//            {
//                $store = $Storage;
//                //echo $store;
//            }
        echo $againAnotherChild[0]."<br>";
        //echo "Storage".$store;
    }
```

**if i do print_r($againAnotherChild) this is what i get which updates after each iteration**

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint8 ) SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [0] => uint8 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => enum )
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint8 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0]
>   => enum ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint8 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => firmware ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => enum )
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => enum ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0]
>   => uint8 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => enum )

------------------------Next Iteration--------------

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => nodeid ) SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [0] => uint8 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => ipaddress )
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => macaddress ) SimpleXMLElement Object
>   ( [0] => enum ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint8 )
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint16 ) SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [0] => uint16 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint16 )
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint16 ) SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [0] => enum ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => enum ) SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [0] => uint16 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint16 )
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => uint16 ) SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [0] => uint16 ) SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => enum )

**How can i put these uint8,uint16 etc into an array that keeps updating till last iteration?**

Comment: obj to array? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345609/296555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution was just to type cast an object to certain data type

```
    $store = (array)againAnotherChildArray;
```

What i did in my code is this

```
                    $nodesWithValues = (array)$anotherChild->children();
                    foreach ($nodesWithValues as $key => $value)
                    {
                        //echo "$key : $value <br>";//CfgVer : uint8
                        var_dump($nodesWithValues);
                    }
```

problem solved by simple **type casting** :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about removing duplicates in array?

Would this help?

```
$againAnotherChildArray[$againAnotherChild->getName()] = $againAnotherChild->getName();
```

That should create something like hash map, eg set of tuples;

Comment: The array is empty what for example  $store [] = againAnotherChildArray[0]; but of course i cannot put values of an XML object in an array.