# PHP: performance oriented way of storing variables in a flat file?

Tags: php, flat-file

I'm looking to store some basic information (just simple variables, not a database) which doesn't require any security (simple strings stored for case sensitivity, lets me skip a MySQL query to improve performance). I'm looking for quickest way to read the contents and create a few variables from those contents. I'm comfortable with how to interact with flat files for the most part, what I want to do is determine the most efficient way of storing a few variables and interpreting back in to PHP please.

PHP I'll store in the flatfile...

```
$case = 'My Site Name CaSiNG';
$string2 = 'some text';
```

Comment: Make it work.  Then make it right.  ***Then*** make it fast.  By that point, you'll have a better idea of what's slowing you down anyway -- and frankly, i doubt it'll be reading "a few variables" no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly fast save for write blocking. I supposed you could also write your variables as strait php which should also be fast

```
$variables = array();
$variables['case'] = 'My site name';
$variables['string2'] = 'some text';

$write_to_file = serialize($variables);

// todo: save $write_to_file
// todo: open saved file and read contents to $write_to_file

$vars = unserialize($write_to_file);
print_r($vars);
```

see [Convert var_dump of array back to array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/code-challenge-convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable) to use var_dump to export all your variables and import them

Comment: I actually just came across serialize and unserialize at php.net. Thanks for actually answering the question and finding a thread where the poster's question was UP voted instead of ridiculed. Both accepted and up-voted.