# Multidimensional array in txt file to php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm developing a tool for a client, and I save the data in a txt file when using the tool offline, so that he can then upload this file onto server and save data in database.

The data in the text file are  presented like below:

```
Array
(
    [idcategorie] => 1
    [idmasteruser] => 1
    [societe] => Company
    [marque] => Brand
    [audit] => AUdit
    [nom] => Baker
    [prenom] => James
    [phone] => 
    [email] => some@some.com
    [nboutils] => 3
    [outil0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [valeurs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 24
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 27
                    [3] => 16
                )

            [file] => /newbam/images-up/HopbV_chefs.jpg
            [notes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 7
                    [3] => 6
                )
           )
)
```

How can I put this data in a PHP array that I can handle after using keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize the array:

http://php.net/serialize

It writes the array in a format that can be saved in a file and parsed later as an object or an array with unserialize:

http://php.net/unserialize

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you easy and simple !
Perfect !

Answer (score 1):

If you used `var_dump` to generate this data, restoring it back into an array is a non-trivial task. However, this is much easier if you export the data [using `var_export` or `serialize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/code-challenge-convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable), which can be put back into an array.