# String to Object conversion

Tags: php, parsing, object

I'm looping through a database table which holds some data related to external API responses.

Someone was saving the responses as text, like so:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["CreateProspectResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
    ["State"]=>
    string(7) "Success"
    ["ErrorMessage"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ReturnValue"]=>
    object(stdClass)#7 (1) {
      ["ProspectID"]=>
      int(304)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm guessing the original developer was doing a `var_dump()` with the `<pre>` tags, and saved the response literally.

When I loop through the Table results, I'm want to convert the string back into an Object, so I can parse it.  Which I'm failing at, badly.

Here's what I've attempted:

```
<?php

$string = '
object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["CreateProspectResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
    ["State"]=>
    string(7) "Success"
    ["ErrorMessage"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["ReturnValue"]=>
    object(stdClass)#7 (1) {
      ["ProspectID"]=>
      int(304)
    }
  }
}
';

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo $xmlObj->CreateProspectResult->State;
?>
```

PHP isn't enjoying my attempts, and giving me non-object-related errors back.

Is it possible to take such a string and convert it back into an Object?

Comment: Update your question with an example of what the API returns or do you not have access to the API directly. Aside from that I don't think there is any ready to go converter from string to stdClass.

Comment: "Someone was saving the responses as text, like so:" --- looooooooool

Comment: I don't have access to the API directly, unfortunately. I'm told the response was what is posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this works for object (seems to be), but this seems to cover your question.

```
function unvar_dump($str) {
    if (strpos($str, "\n") === false) {
        //Add new lines:
        $regex = array(
            '#(\\[.*?\\]=>)#',
            '#(string\\(|int\\(|float\\(|array\\(|NULL|object\\(|})#',
        );
        $str = preg_replace($regex, "\n\\1", $str);
        $str = trim($str);
    }
    $regex = array(
        '#^\\040*NULL\\040*$#m',
        '#^\\s*array\\((.*?)\\)\\s*{\\s*$#m',
        '#^\\s*string\\((.*?)\\)\\s*(.*?)$#m',
        '#^\\s*int\\((.*?)\\)\\s*$#m',
        '#^\\s*float\\((.*?)\\)\\s*$#m',
        '#^\\s*\[(\\d+)\\]\\s*=>\\s*$#m',
        '#\\s*?\\r?\\n\\s*#m',
    );
    $replace = array(
        'N',
        'a:\\1:{',
        's:\\1:\\2',
        'i:\\1',
        'd:\\1',
        'i:\\1',
        ';'
    );
    $serialized = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $str);
    $func = create_function(
        '$match', 
        'return "s:".strlen($match[1]).":\\"".$match[1]."\\"";'
    );
    $serialized = preg_replace_callback(
        '#\\s*\\["(.*?)"\\]\\s*=>#', 
        $func,
        $serialized
    );
    $func = create_function(
        '$match', 
        'return "O:".strlen($match[1]).":\\"".$match[1]."\\":".$match[2].":{";'
    );
    $serialized = preg_replace_callback(
        '#object\\((.*?)\\).*?\\((\\d+)\\)\\s*{\\s*;#', 
        $func, 
        $serialized
    );
    $serialized = preg_replace(
        array('#};#', '#{;#'), 
        array('}', '{'), 
        $serialized
    );

    return unserialize($serialized);
}
```

Source:
[Convert var_dump of array back to array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/code-challenge-convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable)