# Convert string (which is array) back to array

Tags: php, arrays, string, toarray

I've got a problem, if i retrieve a record from a database, it will return as a string. But I don't want that, because it should be an array:

```
var_dump($data)
```

returns

```
string(654) "Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 17-6-2015 [2] => Livingwater TEST [3] => J. Luttik [4] => E. Luttik [5] => Annemarie, Rosy [id] => 7 ) [1] => Array ( [1] => 21-6-2015 [2] => Celebration [3] => P. Brenner [4] => B. Nobbe [5] => Heleen, Laurens [id] => 8 ) [2] => Array ( [1] => 24-6-2015 [2] => Celebration [3] => C. Visser [4] => E. Luttik [5] => Annet, Elsemijn [id] => 9 ) ) "
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Why downvote? tell me what's wrong....

Comment: That is not a format that is easy or even possible to parse back into an array. Why is it in `var_dump` format to begin with?!

Comment: What are the outcome if you do `echo $data;`?

Comment: Found this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable

Comment: @sanderbee That'd be addressing the [wrong problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: FWIW, I've voted to close this as *too broad*. While there may be an immediate answer to your immediate question, this is a symptom of something going quite wrong and it's unclear what exactly should be fixed in the broader scheme of things to bring whatever you're doing there to a professional level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've got it, it's stored wrong into the database. It should be stored as `json_encode($data)`, and retreived as `json_decode($data, true)`.

But an other way is to store it as `serialize($data)` and retreive it with `unserialize($data)`

Comment: Without analyzing the exact contents of the data, I would say this should be at least 2 tables each with multiple columns. If you normalize your database schema, you will be able to easily retrieve, sort, search for, etc. information. Serialized data, like json, in one field makes that next to impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to save the info in the db and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to retrieve it to something useable. I believe it is the best way to do that. You can also use json_encode and json_decode, but I prefer [un]serialize

Comment: Meeeeehhh..... so close... What is "that" exactly? This advice is not wrong, but also far from right.

Comment: the text was not as explicit as I would wanted :)

Comment: OK, better. Though I can't agree with storing `serialize`d data in a database.

Comment: @deceze any specific reason why?

Comment: JSON is more interoperable. Don't count on PHP being the only system wanting to read that data in the long run. If at all reasonable, the data should be normalised to an RDBMS to begin with.

Comment: @deceze fair enough even though with the amount of downvotes it would appear the answer to be totally off :)

Comment: This question is a train wreck in slow motion. Be glad you can't see all the deleted answers. Yours wasn't good enough to survive the immediate downvote convulsion going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the clear fact is that the stored data is stored wrong! To reconstruct this string into an array, you have to do more than just storing it in a right way.

So the solution could be the one from @sanderbee: [Convert var_dump of array back to array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable)

Or my suggested solution would be storing them in a right way.

The data is an array so this means multible data. Either you save it as an serialized string, so you just can unserialize it or I think the better solution would be a **1-N** relation inside the database, like:

Table: Humans

Rows:

- ID
- Name

Table: Pets

- ID
- Human_ID
- Race

So **1 (ONE)** Human can have **N (0 til infinity)** Pets.

Table: Human

- 1, George Bush
- 2, Barack Obama

Table: Pets

- 1, 1, Dog
- 2, 1, Cat
- 3, 1, Delphin
- 4, 2, Putin

So while George Bush has 3 Pets: A dog, a cat and a delphin. Barack Obama just have a putin as a pet.

This way you can easily get all data with one SQL-Query using JOIN statement.

```
$db->query( 'SELECT Human.Name, Pets.race FROM Human JOIN Pets ON ( Human.id = Pets.Human_ID ) ' );
```

Looks much more effort than unserialize? But much cleaner and if you got many data, the database will be much faster than.. or it should be.. also it's more cleaner. Looks more professionell for me.

**Edit**

Your profile looks like your experience should be enough to know this already.. is it possible that you "HAVE TO" use this records in the database? If so, than the very first option from sanderbee is a "must do"..

Comment: I've solved it by using a serialize() when storing it in the database, and unserialize when retrieving it. Works like a charm.

Comment: Yea, yea, many ways leading you to your goal. But keep in mind, that some ways also makes problems follow your way and keep reaching you someday. If you have time you should try the database option too, it's really powerful and when you someday have tons of data to use, you will be thankfull having the experience. Not only it will help you to successfully beat the problem, but also increases your value as a developer for every company hiring :-)

Comment: You're right, but the array wasn't from the database, but a google spreadsheet. So your story about the database is helpful, but not for the problem I had. It was stored as a print_r($value), so that was the problem. I've stored it as an serialize($value) now, and unserialize($value) when I want to get it out. Thanks anyways for your time.