# PhpUnit: how to create examples of data structures for testing?

Tags: php, arrays, unit-testing, phpunit

Say you have a method that receives an array as a parameter. That method does some manipulation with that array and then outputs a different array.

```
public function createArrayForX(array $myArray){
  return $modifiedArray;
}
```

In order for me to test that the output has some values I need to create some sample cases for my input. It is a tedious work to create arrays manually, especially big ones.

```
public function testCreateArrayForX(){
  $myArray = []; // **how do I easily create myArray here**
  $this->assertContains("String that I want", $this->sampleClass->createArrayForX($myArray));
}
```

I tried something like var_dumping my array in the program, copying the result from var_dump and transforming it back to array ([Convert var_dump of array back to array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable)) and then edit it to make different tests. Is there a simple way or am I doing things wrong if I need this?

So my question is how do you **easily create a skeleton for you sample input** that you can then change to test different scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(var_export($myArray, true));
```

in the program gave me what I need.