# Php trying to get property of-non-object

Tags: php

I trying to get data from a webservices using php curl. I get this data 
var_dump($result) result is

```
string(136) "array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2) { ["guid"]=>    string(23) "149063186158d93cb600485" ["stage"]=> int(0) } } "
```

I want to get guid and stage. When I use this code

```
$result->guid
```

I get an error. How can I solve this problem?

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

```
print_r($result) is array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2) { ["guid"]=> string(23) "149063186158d93cb600485" ["stage"]=> int(0) } }
```

Comment: try `$result[0]->guid `

Comment: I tried such as I get same error.

Comment: You have a string here. Show us your code, which created this string.

Comment: Check the best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531857/convert-var-dump-of-array-back-to-array-variable

Comment: I'm using curl. Returning data is as I showed.

Comment: @Fatih can u show me the content by using ```print_r()``` once.

Comment: print_r($result) is array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2) { ["guid"]=> string(23) "149063186158d93cb600485" ["stage"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: This looks like a `var_dump` of a `var_dump` of an `array`.

Comment: are you having any object or just a string? because var_dump display string(136) menas that is an string not an object or array? can you confirm the same

Comment: from ```print_r``` output it seems ```$result[0]->guid``` should work. Use ```json_encode``` & show me the result once. That'll help to see the things in our own local environment.

Comment: The output you posted says `$result` contains the output of a `var_dump()` call and that one is not JSON and cannot be easily decoded into something useful. Please post the raw JSON you get from the remote service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo (is_array($result)) ? $result[0]->guid : $result->guid;
```