# Store array within a string as an array

Tags: php, wordpress

Within the `wp_posts` WordPress table, I have a row stored for a post (custom post type) that literally stores the following within the `post_content` column:

```
Array
(
    [test_price] => 39.00
    [test_elegibility] => Eligible
    [test_confirmation] => confirmed
    [test_id] => DUA6A44THQH7U
    ...
)
```

When I query the table via the following:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_type = "custom_post_type"' );

foreach($query as $q) {
    $content = $q->post_content;
    var_dump($content);
}
```

The result of the var_dump for each variable above is obviously as follows:

```
string(1369) string(1311)
```

and so on since the `post_content` field, which is essentially saved as a string for my purposes at the moment, contains the array I'm trying to pull out.

I know I can strip / filter out the brackets, square brackets, etc and cycle through each instance to create an associative array directly from the `post_content` field value quite easily, which is fine.

My question is, am I missing a trick where I can simply assign the strings as arrays immediately by simply assigning them to variables? For example, using the above:

```
foreach($query as $q) {
    $content = $q->post_content;
    var_dump($content);
}
```

The result would be that each `var_dump` should ideally print out:

```
array(2) { 'te' => string(4) "werg" 'wreg' => string(6) "werefg" }
```

NOTE - the field values will only ever contain the arrays, there's nothing else appended or prepended...

Comment: If I understand your question, you can serialize the array while saving the data in `post_content` field and then unserialized it when you are rendering. But the best option is to use `postmeta` table  for your custom requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you probably want to use the PHP [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) method which will return a string representation of your array that you can then store in the database.
You can then use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get the data out of the string again.

If you're desperate for a way to reparse a `var_dump` output to an array you can check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531880/7326037 but it's not pretty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - in the end I did use serialize, among a couple of other things too!