# Convert a PHP string array into an Array object

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm developing a PHP app and I have a problem by converting a string array into an object array. I tried to force casting my string into an array by using (array), but it won't works. Here is my string (debug):

`string '['method'=>'post','action'=>'#']' (length=32)`

As you can see, it's a perfect array into a string and i want to convert that string.

My question is simple, does PHP has a function to convert directly a string into an array (I think no) or i have to convert my string by using explode?

Comment: how/where do you get this string?

Comment: Seriously, I would consider changing something in your application, if there is a case where you need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From php 5.4 you can simply eval:
eval("\$f=['method'=>'post','action'=>'#'];");
var_dump($f);

For olders you have to fix the string a bit, change the 1st "[" to "array(" and the last "]" to ")".

The question is a bit duplicate of [How to create an array from output of var_dump in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425921/how-to-create-an-array-from-output-of-var-dump-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the fast AND correct reply! I forgot that eval function ;)

Comment: Careful using eval though _never ever_ use it with user input ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you define an array.
But before writing code, please **take a look at** [manuels](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
$arrayName = array('method' => 'post', 'action' => '#');
```

The output will read

```
array (size=2)
  'method' => string 'post' (length=4)
  'action' => string '#' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and `foreach()` to make this work:

```
$str = "['method'=>'post','action'=>'#']";

$splitArray = preg_split("/[,']+/", $str);
foreach ($splitArray as $k => $val) {
  if ($val == '=>') {
    $newArr[$splitArray[$k - 1]] =  $splitArray[$k + 1];
  }
}

var_dump($newArr);
/*newArr
Array
(
  [method] => post
  [action] => #
)*/
```